# Test Class code coverage error: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: soql, unit-test

Having some issues with my test class code coverage. It's at 90% coverage but will not allow me to deploy to production because of this error:

> "System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject"

Stack Trace:

`"Class.deleteRowsDevNotes.onloadmethod: line 16, column 1
Class.deleteRowsDevNotesTest3.start: line 50, column 1"`

Can anybody assist by pointing out what needs to be added to my "start" method?

Class:

```
    public class deleteRowsDevNotes {
//Variable to hold all accounts added/edited
public List<Sales_Dev_Notes__c> allContactList = new List<Sales_Dev_Notes__c>();

//Variable to hold add contacts to be deleted
public List<Sales_Dev_Notes__c> deleteContactList = new List<Sales_Dev_Notes__c>();

//Variable to hold the Contact record
public User accountRec {get;set;}

//Called when the page loads initially from the "action" method on the apex:page. Populates the Account record and the releated contact list
    public void onloadmethod() {

     List<Sales_Dev_Notes__c> allContactList1 = new List<Sales_Dev_Notes__c>();
     String aid =System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('id');
     accountRec = [SELECT Id,Name,Profile.Name,Title,ManagerId,Extension,Current_Month_Quota__c,UserRole.Name FROM User WHERE Id=:aid]; 
     allContactList = [SELECT Id, OwnerId, CreatedById, CreatedDate, Notes__c, Coach_Type__c, Creator__c, Note_Date__c, Action__c FROM Sales_Dev_Notes__c WHERE OwnerId=:accountRec.Id ORDER BY Note_Date__c DESC];
}
//Send the list of contacts to the visualforce page
public List<Sales_Dev_Notes__c> getContacts(){
    return allContactList;
}

//Add a temporary contact to the table. Not saved to the database
public void addContact(){
    Sales_Dev_Notes__c c = new Sales_Dev_Notes__c();
    allContactList.add(c);
}

//Remove a contact from the table.
public void removeContact(){
    Integer indexVal = Integer.valueof(system.currentpagereference().getparameters().get('index'));
    //If the contact is an existing contact then add it to the list to delete from the databse
    if(allContactList[indexVal - 1].Id != null)
        deleteContactList.add(allContactList[indexVal - 1]);
    //Remove the contact from the table    
    allContactList.remove(indexVal - 1);            
}    
public void saveChanges(){
    //update existing contacts and insert new ones
    upsert allContactList;
    //delete the contacts that were removed
    if(deleteContactList.size() > 0)
        delete deleteContactList;
}    

}
```

AND Test Class:

```
    @isTest
private class deleteRowsDevNotesTest3 {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
        deleteRowsDevNotes  clsObj = new deleteRowsDevNotes();
        /*Sales_Dev_Notes__c acct =  new Sales_Dev_Notes__c();
        acct.Name = 'testAccount';*/

        Apexpages.currentpage().getParameters().put('index','1');

       clsObj.addContact();


        clsObj.saveChanges();  
        clsObj.removeContact();  
    }

     static testmethod void start()
   {

   User accountRec1 = New User();
   accountRec1.LastName =  'Test';
   accountRec1.Alias = 'aTest';
   accountRec1.Email = 'aTest@test.com';
   accountRec1.Username = 'aTest@weddingwire.com';
   accountRec1.CommunityNickname = 'aTest';
   accountRec1.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
   accountRec1.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
   accountRec1.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
   accountRec1.TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles';
   accountRec1.ProfileId = '00e50000001Be3P';
   accountRec1.IsActive = true;
   Insert accountRec1 ; 

   system.runas(accountRec1) {
   date runtime=system.today();
   Sales_Dev_Notes__c allContactList1 = New Sales_Dev_Notes__c();
   allContactList1.Notes__c =  'Test';
   allContactList1.Coach_Type__c = 'aTest';
   allContactList1.Creator__c = 'Paul Gentile';
   allContactList1.Action__c = 'aTest@weddingwire.com';
   allContactList1.OwnerId = '00550000001R0Fl';
   allContactList1.Note_Date__c = runtime;
   Insert allContactList1 ; 

   deleteRowsDevNotes qdnc = new deleteRowsDevNotes();
   test.starttest();
   qdnc.accountRec = accountRec1;

   qdnc.onloadmethod();


   qdnc.clone();

   qdnc.addContact();

   qdnc.saveChanges();

test.stoptest();

}
   }


   static testMethod void testdeleteRowsDevNotes() {
deleteRowsDevNotes clsObj = new deleteRowsDevNotes();
    Test.startTest();
    Sales_Dev_Notes__c [] notes = clsObj.getContacts();
    Test.stopTest();
    System.assertNotEquals(null, notes);
    }

}
```

Comment: Which line is 50, and which one is 16?

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, you need to assign userId which you are trying to retrieve in `onloadmethod()` method and using that in SOQL.

Also, you have to create the `Sales_Dev_Notes__c` record with the ownerId as `accountRec1.Id`.

finally, remove hard coded id in the test class.

And follow best practices (as no assert statements are found in your method.)

Refer [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests) and [Testing Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_best_practices.htm)

The updated code is:

```
static testmethod void start()
   {

       User accountRec1 = New User();
       accountRec1.LastName =  'Test';
       accountRec1.Alias = 'aTest';
       accountRec1.Email = 'aTest@test.com';
       accountRec1.Username = 'aTest@weddingwire.com';
       accountRec1.CommunityNickname = 'aTest';
       accountRec1.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
       accountRec1.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
       accountRec1.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
       accountRec1.TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles';
       accountRec1.ProfileId = '00e50000001Be3P';
       accountRec1.IsActive = true;
       Insert accountRec1 ; 

   system.runas(accountRec1) {
       date runtime=system.today();
       Sales_Dev_Notes__c allContactList1 = New Sales_Dev_Notes__c();
       allContactList1.Notes__c =  'Test';
       allContactList1.Coach_Type__c = 'aTest';
       allContactList1.Creator__c = 'Paul Gentile';
       allContactList1.Action__c = 'aTest@weddingwire.com';
       allContactList1.OwnerId = accountRec1.id;  //'00550000001R0Fl';
       allContactList1.Note_Date__c = runtime;
       Insert allContactList1 ; 

       deleteRowsDevNotes qdnc = new deleteRowsDevNotes();
       test.starttest();

       qdnc.accountRec = accountRec1;
       Apexpages.currentpage().getParameters().put('id',accountRec1.Id);

       qdnc.onloadmethod();


       qdnc.clone();

       qdnc.addContact();

       qdnc.saveChanges();

        test.stoptest();

    }
 }
```